# scaling php mysql shopping cart database

Tags: php, mysql

Although the topic is quite trivial but I am still confused what could be the best design. So I am trying build a php mysql based website. The idea is to have user registrations, as well as store items in current shopping cart into database and also store purchased items record per user. (I Plan to serialize items, maybe comma seperated string with Produt IDs and then deserialize upon retrieval from DB)

In the beginning it looks trivial, but lets imagine there are a million users.
Now i wonder how this design should scale.

My initial idea is to have a simple table with EMAIL - ID (autogenerated)
And then use this id to generate further table containing Name, Address, Phone, Password
And another table with current items as well as purchased items in the past against that ID.

So based on this ID, i can query all these tables for quick reference.

Do you think this idea would scale good lets say with a million users accounting for 3-4 million tables. Or i should try to squeeze everything in a single table??

Comment: you should definitely use 3rd normal form to optimize the data structures.

Comment: 1. Worrying about facebook-level technical challenges when you're at the initial design stage is just going to have you spending a lot of time designing and implementing vastly overcomplicated things that won't be necessary for years, if ever. 2. Dynamically-generated tables are basically always a terrible idea. 3. Storing serialized data is usually a bad idea as well, as it cannot be queried efficiently. Recommendation: Read up on normalization: https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html A properly normalized database scales well and is generally easy to work with.

Comment: Randy @Sammitch Thank you, that was an excellent article. So ignoring the issues with scaling, the right design as i understand is to be as much granular as possible until there are no transitive dependencies left. I'll try it out, thx